# How deactivate the deprecation log in TYPO3

Tags: typo3, typo3-9.x

In TYPO3 9.5 LTS the deprecation log is not deactivated when choosing the "Configuration Preset" "Live". How is it possible to deactivate the deprecation log in 9.5 LTS?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since TYPO3v9 the deprecation log is basically a regular [log like any other](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/master/en-us/ApiOverview/Logging/Index.html) and should be configured as such.

This means a single logging framework configuration line can disable the deprecation log:

```php
$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['LOG']['TYPO3']['CMS']['deprecations']['writerConfiguration'][\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Log\LogLevel::NOTICE] = [];
```

Notice (heh) that obviously fixing all deprecation notices should be preferred since the notices exist for a reason. Without any change you will most likely run into breaking changes on future TYPO3 updates. The [Extension Scanner](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/master/en-us/ApiOverview/ExtensionScanner/Index.html) built into TYPO3 can help you here to get an overview.

Please see [Deprecation log handling in TYPO3 9](https://blog.reelworx.at/detail/deprecation-log-handling-in-typo3-9/) for a more in-depth explanation.

Comment: Thanks! I put this line in my AdditionalConfiguration.php and it seems to work - mostly. But i get this line in the log: 
10-03-20 10:07: GeneralUtility::deprecationLog() will be removed in TYPO3 v10.0, use "trigger_error("Given reason", E_USER_DEPRECATED);" to log deprecations. I presume it results from news or any other extensions. There are a few which uses deprecation log on there own. With a deprecated function ... :-)

Comment: @lisardo that inconsistency might also come from the Core and is about to be tackled https://review.typo3.org/c/Packages/TYPO3.CMS/+/63071